# Question About Theory Behind A Solution

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to understand the theory behind a solution to a problem posed by my Statistics Professor earlier today.

The problem: [image]

The solution: [image]

I tried an alternative solution to this beforehand, essentially using the Product Rule for each digit of the sequence by multiplying 4 * 5 * … * 5 and adding it to 5^10.

What makes this solution (the more correct one) better than my attempt?

EDIT: Alternative methods to doing this problem are appreciated, but I really would like to understand the intuition behind the answer given above. It is something I will have to be able to replicate, and I will not think of such notion under pressure unless I have some sort of knowledge about its usefulness.

EDIT 2: Thanks for the formatting help!!

Comment: Do you understand why your solution doesn't work? E.g. if the second digit is 2, how many possibilities are there for the third?

Comment: I believe numbers can be repeated, just that the odd/even sequence must be apparent. I just edited my solution since I had forgotten part of it.

Comment: To clarify, we could have $121\ldots, 122\ldots, 123\ldots, 124\ldots, \ldots$, but your rule of product only allows for 5 options.

Comment: OH, I see now. Can you explain, then, the actual theory of the solution? I've tried expanding the terms of the series and I just don't see the intuition in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea that "I believe it is supposed to represent the number of sequences such that no two odd numbers are adjacent WITHOUT the constraint of the first digit being one or greater, subtracting the number of sequences including the above constraint." is correct.

---

Let's count the number of 10 digit strings where no 2 odd numbers are consecutive.

We can condition on the number of odd digits. Clearly, there are at most 5.

If there are $k$ odd digits, then show that

- There are ${ 10 - k + 1 \choose k} $ places for the odd digits to be in
- There are $5^k$ possibilities for the odd digits.
- There are $5^{10-k}$ possibilities for the even digits.

---

Let's count the number of 9 digit strings where no 2 odd numbers are consecutive.

We can condition on the number of odd digits. Clearly, there are at most 5.

If there are $k$ odd digits, then show that

- There are ${ 9 - k + 1 \choose k} $ places for the odd digits to be in
- There are $5^k$ possibilities for the odd digits.
- There are $5^{9-k}$ possibilities for the even digits.

---

Hence, the number of 10 digit strings where no 2 odd numbers are consecutive, and the first digit is 1 or more is

$$ \sum_{k=0}^5 { 10-k+1 \choose k } 5^k 5^{10 - k }  - \sum_{k=0}^5 { 9 - k+1 \choose k } 5^k 5^{9-k}$$

Comment: Huh. That seems incredibly simple. How can I be aware that this is the proceeding for a question similar to this in the future? Additionally, why are the individual parts in your bulleted lists multiplied together? Are they separate tasks under the Product Rule?

Comment: For such counting questions, it helps to develop a sense of what is "hard" about the problem, and then working around it. In this case, the restriction that "first digit is $\geq 1$" is hard, because it would be so nice if it could be 0. So, wishful thinking tells us to allow it to be 0 (first step) and then account for the cases where it is 0 (second step). If you look at my other solution (assuming you understand recurrence relations), the $T_{1,e} =4$ deals with exactly this issue.

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense. I assume that the different factors are being multiplied together within each term because of the Product Rule?

Comment: Yes. $  $ $ $ $  $

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to set up a recurrence relation.

Let $ T_{n,o}$ be the number of n-digit strings where 1) first digit is 1 or more, 2) no 2 odd numbers are consecutive and 3) the last digit is odd.

Let $T_{n,e}$ be the number of n-digit strings where 1) first digit is 1 or more, 2) no 2 odd numbers are consecutive and 3) the last digit is odd.

Then, we have $T_{1, o} = 5, T_{1,e} = 4 $ as the starting conditions, and

$$T_{n+1, o} = 5T_{n,e}, T_{n+1, e } = 5T_{n, e} + 5T_{n, o}$$

Hence, $T_{10, o } + T_{10, e } = 1232421875$.

Comment: Our section of the textbook from which this comes calls for the answer I provided above. Can you explain that in a more understandable manner.

Comment: Which section is it in? Please specify that if you want a particular approach to be used in the solution.

Comment: It is essentially in a section about the Binomial Theorem, though it is not explicitly titled as such. And I am not looking for a solution, but rather an EXPLANATION of the solution above, if that helps.

Comment: Can you write your formula clearly? It is unclear to me what it represents (and thus I have no idea what it's supposed to represent) E.g. What is the second summation to? Is the power a $4-k$ or a $9-k$?

Comment: I am trying to understand what it represents aswell, so explaining it is near impossible. I believe it is supposed to represent the number of sequences such that no two odd numbers are adjacent WITHOUT the constraint of the first digit being one or greater, subtracting the number of sequences including the above constraint.

Comment: I suspect you are right. But I'm unable to make out the second term clearly. All I'm asking is for you to reproduce the formula clearly.

Comment: I rewrote the formula; it should be clearer. I apologize, I forgot to mention that.